# how i can change this function to icons with numbers marker_blue1.png marker_blue2.png ... with hover marker_yellow1.png marker_yellow2.png

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 
how i can change this function of icons marker of map api v3 to icons with numbers thx for your help
          var side_bar_html = "";

```
      // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
      // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
      var gmarkers = []; 
      var gicons = [];
     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;
gicons["red"] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./mapIcons/marker_red.png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
  // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
  // in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
  // increase in the X direction to the right and in
  // the Y direction down.

  var iconImage = new google.maps.MarkerImage('./mapIcons/marker_red.png',
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 9,34.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
  var iconShadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('./mapIcons/shadow50.png',
      // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
      // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
      new google.maps.Size(37, 34),
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      new google.maps.Point(0, 10));
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
  var iconShape = {
      coord: [9,0,6,1,4,2,2,4,0,8,0,12,1,14,2,16,5,19,7,23,8,26,9,30,9,34,11,34,11,30,12,26,13,24,14,21,16,18,18,16,20,12,20,8,18,4,16,2,15,1,13,0],
      type: 'poly'
  };

function getMarkerImage(iconColor) {
   if ((typeof(iconColor)=="undefined") || (iconColor==null)) { 
      iconColor = "red"; 
   }
   if (!gicons[iconColor]) {
      gicons[iconColor] = new google.maps.MarkerImage("./mapIcons/marker_"+ iconColor +".png",
      // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 34 pixels tall.
      new google.maps.Size(20, 34),
      // The origin for this image is 0,0.
      new google.maps.Point(0,0),
      // The anchor for this image is at 6,20.
      new google.maps.Point(9, 34));
   } 
   return gicons[iconColor];

}

      gicons["blue"] = getMarkerImage("blue");
      gicons["green"] = getMarkerImage("green");
      gicons["yelow"] = getMarkerImage("yellow");
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng,name,html,color) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: gicons[color],
        shadow: iconShadow,
        map: map,
        title: name,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
infowindow.close();
        });
        // Switch icon on marker mouseover and mouseout
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {
          marker.setIcon(gicons["yellow"]);
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {
          marker.setIcon(gicons["blue"]);
        });
    gmarkers.push(marker);
    // add a line to the side_bar html
    var marker_num = gmarkers.length-1;
    side_bar_html += '<a href="javascript:myclick(' + marker_num + ')"  onmouseover="javascript:myclick(' + marker_num + ')" onmouseover="gmarkers['+marker_num+'].setIcon(gicons.yellow)" onmouseout="gmarkers['+marker_num+'].setIcon(gicons.blue)">' + name + '<\/a><br>';
}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "mouseover");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's Chart tools for dynamic creation

http://biostall.com/adding-number-or-letters-to-google-maps-api-markers
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/dynamic_icons.html

read the section "Pins"